# cant click submit button using HTMLElementCollection?

Tags: c#

```
<fieldset><b>&nbsp;</b><button id="submit" class="googleCheckPosButt" 
   onclick="docSubmit()">CHECK</button></fieldset>
</form>
```

This is a source code of a webpage where I am trying to put data into the form and submit it but I am successful in entering data into the text fields of webpage but I am unable to click it

```
theElementCollection = 
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
{
        if (curElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("submit"))
        {
           curElement.InvokeMember("click");                   
        }
}
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: Can you add docSubmit() code?

Comment: Formatting your code and code goes a long way in getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query doesn't ever get the submit button. You need to change it to this:

```
theElementCollection = 
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
```

---

For the problem you mentioned in your comments, you should probably use the [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event to click the button.

Comment: No i have used the same code for clicking a button on another website and it worked??

Comment: its pressing the submit button before the url is load into the webbrowser it give an error that "an error has occcured in script on this page" and it presses the submit button but do not do anything...plzz help?

Comment: @user2233501 I updated my answer. Put your code inside the `DocumentCompleted` event

Comment: i did     this     but its not working and in button1_click i am running the function mentioned above                                                                          webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new   WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(button1_Click);